# sendkeys.send("{Tab}") does'nt work on command button in vb.net 2015

Tags: vb.net

I am developing a POS in vb.net and want to use Enter key as tab. this works well in controls other than button. e.g when the focus is on textbox or combobox etc then it works good but if the focused control is button then it does not move to next control. Help me by fixing this problem, I have searched alot but could not find any solution regarding this.
thanks

Regards

Muhammad Irfan Sumra

Comment: Pretty sure you send the **tab** to the owner window of the button not the button iteself

Comment: How you use `sendkeys.send` in asp.net application?

Comment: yes I used form_keypress event.

Comment: The `Enter` key already has a job for `Buttons`, i.e. to click them.

Comment: You could try creating your own button that inherits the standard button and override its behaviour so that the Enter key does nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Enter` key for button have default behavior which raise `Click` event.

You can handle `Click` event for moving focus to next control, and use `MouseClick` event for your click logic

```
Private Sub MyButton_Click() Handles MyButton.Click
    SendKeys.Send("{TAB}")
End Sub

Private Sub MyButton_MouseClick() Handles MyButton.MouseClick
    ' Do your click logic
End Sub
```